# PageLoad on a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, gridview-sorting, scroll-paging

When the page initially loads, it has only a TextBox1 and a Button. If I don't enter anything in the box and hit the button, it will load my GridView with all the Data rows from the SQL Select. 
Q - How can I make it that when the page loads initially, it will do that on it's own (load all the rows)?

This search function I have found in a YouTube video and does exactly what I need. Like I said, brand new to ASP, but if need be, let me know and I can change it.

GridView1 :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="265px" Height="22px" CssClass="myBox"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Search Fields" CssClass="myButton" />
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" CellPadding="4" EnableModelValidation="True" EnableTheming="True" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="100%" style="margin-top: 0px; text-align: center;" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" >
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind (DB name and Password taken out):

```
SqlConnection vid = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ENF;Initial Catalog=***Database Name***;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=***Password***");
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String str = "SELECT ab.NAME as [Customer] ,ISNULL(ab.TELEPHONE1,'') as [Phone #] ,ISNULL(pb.NAME,'') as [Product] ,ISNULL(aeb.NEW_PRODUCTVERSION,'') as [Version] ,CASE WHEN ab.STATUSCODE = 1 THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Inactive' END as [Status] ,ISNULL('Sal : ' + c.SALUTATION + ' / ','') + ISNULL('Title : ' + c.JOBTITLE + ' / ','') + ISNULL(a.PRIMARYCONTACTIDNAME,'') as [Primary Contact] ,ISNULL(c.TELEPHONE1,'') as [Contact Phone] FROM ACCOUNTBASE ab LEFT JOIN ACCOUNTEXTENSIONBASE aeb on ab.ACCOUNTID = aeb.ACCOUNTID LEFT JOIN PRODUCTBASE pb on aeb.NEW_PRIMARYPRODUCTID = pb.PRODUCTID LEFT JOIN ACCOUNT a on ab.ACCOUNTID = a.ACCOUNTID LEFT JOIN CONTACT c on a.PRIMARYCONTACTID = c.CONTACTID WHERE ((ab.NAME LIKE '%' + @search + '%') OR (aeb.NEW_PRODUCTVERSION LIKE '%' + @search + '%') OR (pb.NAME LIKE '%' + @search + '%') OR (a.PRIMARYCONTACTIDNAME LIKE '%' + @search + '%')) ORDER BY ab.NAME";
    SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand(str, vid);
    xp.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;

    vid.Open();
    xp.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = xp;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "Name");
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    vid.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're question isn't specific in that you are asking too many questions. However, for the PageLoad issue...

You could move the database call to a new method, and set the GridViews datasource and call the DataBind() method on the Page_Load Event.. Something like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = GetData();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

}

private DataSet GetData()
{
    String str = "SELECT ab.NAME as [Customer] ,ISNULL(ab.TELEPHONE1,'') as [Phone #] ,ISNULL(pb.NAME,'') as [Product] ,ISNULL(aeb.NEW_PRODUCTVERSION,'') as [Version] ,CASE WHEN ab.STATUSCODE = 1 THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Inactive' END as [Status] ,ISNULL('Sal : ' + c.SALUTATION + ' / ','') + ISNULL('Title : ' + c.JOBTITLE + ' / ','') + ISNULL(a.PRIMARYCONTACTIDNAME,'') as [Primary Contact] ,ISNULL(c.TELEPHONE1,'') as [Contact Phone] FROM ACCOUNTBASE ab LEFT JOIN ACCOUNTEXTENSIONBASE aeb on ab.ACCOUNTID = aeb.ACCOUNTID LEFT JOIN PRODUCTBASE pb on aeb.NEW_PRIMARYPRODUCTID = pb.PRODUCTID LEFT JOIN ACCOUNT a on ab.ACCOUNTID = a.ACCOUNTID LEFT JOIN CONTACT c on a.PRIMARYCONTACTID = c.CONTACTID WHERE ((ab.NAME LIKE '%' + @search + '%') OR (aeb.NEW_PRODUCTVERSION LIKE '%' + @search + '%') OR (pb.NAME LIKE '%' + @search + '%') OR (a.PRIMARYCONTACTIDNAME LIKE '%' + @search + '%')) ORDER BY ab.NAME";
    SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand(str, vid);
    xp.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;

    vid.Open();
    xp.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = xp;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "Name");    
    vid.Close();

    return ds;
}
```

Comment: I get this error:
Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0161: '_Default.GetData()': not all code paths return a value

Comment: private DataTable GetData() - is the line highlited red